# Geo_Point Property not indexing as expected

Tags: c#, geolocation, elasticsearch, nest, geopoints

I am using NEST .net client for Elastic Search. I have an Address class with Location Property  in it.

```
public class Address
{
public string AddressLine1 {get;set;}
public string AddressLine2 {get;set;}
public string City {get;set;}
public string State {get;set;}
public string ZipCode {get;set;}
[ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.geo_point)]
public GeoLocation Location {get;set;}
}


public class GeoLocation
{
public float Lat {get;set;}
public float Lon {get;set;}
}
```

I have decorated the Location property with ElasticProperty Attribute geo_point type. I was able to build index for this type. But When i try to get the mapping for this,

```
http://localhost:9200/mysite/Address/_mapping
```

i am expecting the Location property to be of "geo_point" type instead it shows something like this.

```
{
    "Address": {
        "properties": {                
            "location": {
                "properties": {
                    "lat": {
                        "type": "double"
                    },
                    "lon": {
                        "type": "double"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example of how to map a GeoPoint using Nest along with setting other properties. Hopefully helps someone in thefuture.

```
public class Location
{
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
    public decimal Lon { get; set; }
}

public class Building : BaseEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<Location> Location { get; set; }
}

public void CreateBuildingMapping()
{
    var nodes = new List<Uri>() { ... };
    var connectionPool = new Elasticsearch.Net.ConnectionPool.SniffingConnectionPool(nodes);
    var connectionSettings = new Nest.ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, "myIndexName");
    var elasticsearchClient = new Nest.ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var putMappingDescriptor = new Nest.PutMappingDescriptor<Building>(connectionSettings);
    putMappingDescriptor.DateDetection(false);
    putMappingDescriptor.Dynamic(false);
    putMappingDescriptor.IncludeInAll(true);
    putMappingDescriptor.IgnoreConflicts(false);
    putMappingDescriptor.Index("myIndexName");
    putMappingDescriptor.MapFromAttributes();
    putMappingDescriptor
        .MapFromAttributes()
            .Properties(p =>
                p.GeoPoint(s =>
                    s.Name(n => n.Location).IndexGeoHash().IndexLatLon().GeoHashPrecision(12)
                )
            );
    putMappingDescriptor.NumericDetection(false);

    elasticsearchClient.Map(putMappingDescriptor);
}
```

I used Vinoths code from his comment.

Comment: The IndexGeoHash() property does not exist any more. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Please use the `MapFluent()` method to specify mappings. The attribute based mapping is very limitted in what it can express. In the next release MapFluent will be renamed to Map and it will be the only way to specify the mapping.

See this example for mapping a `geo_point` type:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs#L225

Comment: client.MapFluent<Address>(m => m.MapFromAttributes().Properties(p => p.GeoPoint(s => s.Name(n => n.Location).IndexGeoHash().IndexLatLon().GeoHashPrecision(12)))); I did this but still getting the same result. Can you let me know if this right?

Comment: Hi Martijn, I just got to know you are the owner of NEST. Can you help me with this? i am kind of stuck on this for 1 day. I am using Nest0.12.0 version

Comment: @Martijn Laarman Can you please help poit to and updated example. The link seems down.

Answer (score 0):

Create elastic client

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).SetDefaultIndex("my_indexone");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
client.CreateIndex("my_indexone", s => s.AddMapping<VehicleRecords>(f => f.MapFromAttributes().Properties(p => p.GeoPoint(g => g.Name(n => n.Coordinate ).IndexLatLon()))));
```

Create below class

```
              public class VehicleRecords
                {

                    public string name { get; set; }
                    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
                    public double Distance { get; set; }
                }

                public class Coordinate
                {
                    public double Lat { get; set; }
                    public double Lon { get; set; }
                }

          Step 2 :Insert some record using above class
          Step 3 :Using below query to search....


 Nest.ISearchResponse<VehicleRecords> Response = client.Search<VehicleRecords>(s => s.Sort(sort => sort.OnField(f => f.Year).Ascending()).From(0).Size(10).Filter(fil => fil.GeoDistance(n => n.Coordinate, d => d.Distance(Convert.ToDouble(100), GeoUnit.Miles).Location(73.1233252, 36.2566525))));
```